# How can be load Make 3D Dataset Calculated Depth and Images

Tags: python, computer-vision, tensorflow2.0

I'm new in this Field. I have no idea to load Make3D dataset images and his calculated depth.

Dataset Link : [Make 3D](http://make3d.cs.cornell.edu/data.html)

How can be Load the Make3D dataset using `Tensorflow` 2  For Depth Estimation (python) and I have Tensorflow `2.11.0`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.